# Fill out menu with items width

Tags: html, css, drupal-7

I am making a website http://www.5eren.dk/ , and the main menu does not have that many items, so I was wondering how to make the items fill out the whole menu row?

It is the horizontal menu on top of the page of http://www.5eren.dk/

Comment: Please copy/paste a simplified version of your HTML/CSS code here. Your website will eventually change, but this question will stay.

Comment: -1: This question will suffer link rot, soon. Please include a small self-contained example of your problem. -- edit: close-voting because as-is, it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not bullet-proof if menu comes from cms or there are mobile versions but:
CSS solution:

add to the existing code:

```
#header-menu ul.menu {
   width:100%
   display:table
}
```

and:

```
#header-menu ul.menu li{
   display:table-cell;
   float:none
}
```

Comment: this worked for me.. thank you very much :) no worries about the mobile version since im going to use dropdown in mobile browser.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing which you can do is give `#header-menu ul.menu li` a width, that is

```
width:20%;
```

Its done!

Comment: thank you for your answer but i am going to add more menu items, and then 20% wont add up :)